# Loading a UDEC3 or DEC3N datatype in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I have a model format that I am trying to load that was designed around Direct3D 9. The geometry data is stored in a buffer and the position and datatypes of the elements are stored in a [D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I am having trouble reading in UDEC3 and DEC3N datatypes though.

Now from research it seems the datatype GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2 and GL_INT_10_10_10_2 correspond to this, however I keep getting "Invalid Enumeration" no matter what profile I use. Getting the extension "GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2" returns false. However GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV does work and in the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#D3D_compatibility) they mention to use this instead with the GL_BGRA as a size value. Sadly GL_BGRA gives an access violation (though size 4 does not).

What is the correct way to load these datatypes?

**Edited**

Here is how it's set:

```
DX9VertexElement element;

int components = GLHelper.getComponents(element.datatype); //Gets size of DX9 datatype (1, 2,3, etc). Basically a switch that returns based on element.datatype.
int datatype = GLHelper.getDatatype(element.datatype);
int stride = 0;

//Set offset and size of buffer
ByteBuffer origin = mesh.vertBuffer.duplicate();    
if (element.stream == 0)            
{
    origin.position(element.offset);
    stride = mesh.vertexSize;
}
else        
{
    origin.position(mesh.numVerts*mesh.vertexSize + element.offset);
    stride = mesh.auxVertexSize;
}

switch (element.usage){ //Cut out all the other ones to shrink this
    case 4://Tex Coord
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(shader.getAttribTexCoord(), components, datatype, true, stride, origin);
}
```

In this case, the variable components will be GL_BGRA and variable datatype will be "GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV" (or the unsigned version).

Answer (score 1):

#### What platform are you actually using?

`GL_OES_...` will only exist if you are running OpenGL ES. Moreover, that extension you mentioned does not provide that enum. It provides something similar, called `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2_OES` (**0x8DF6**). However, that is a different enumerant than the equivalent data type in desktop OpenGL `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2{_EXT}` (**0x8036**) - provided by `GL_EXT_packed_pixels` and core in GL 1.2+.

The reversed format is provided by [`GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev.txt) and core in GL 3.3+ and ES 3.0+. The extension specification states the following:

> Dependencies with `GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra`
>
> > If `GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra` is not supported, remove references to `GL_BGRA` as an allowed parameter for ***`<size>`*** in `glVertexAttrib`.

*If you are getting an invalid enum, it may be because you are confusing OpenGL's two different APIs.*

Comment: I should have added, I am using the JOGL implementation, which aliases GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2_OES to GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2. Both of these return the numbers you mentioned (0x8DF6 and 0x8036).

I may be just using the profile wrong, but even setting the GLProfile to OpenGL ES (or as the library calls it, GL2ES2) it returns invalid enum.

Comment: @loncannon: Unless you're running this on a smart phone, PDA or some other embedded device, I would forget about the ES2 profile altogether. My NV and AMD GPUs do not offer a single OES extension, you might get them through ANGLE (which many web browsers layer WebGL on top of), but if you run your application on a regular desktop you will not.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that ES2 was outright unsupported. Makes sense why these extensions were not working. Ok, so is there still a way to load those data types using desktop OGL?

Comment: @Ioncannon: Absolutely, it's more likely they'll be supported in desktop GL anyway. The relevant extensions are `GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev` and `GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra`. Both of those extensions are very mature, any hardware that actually supports those data types should have a driver that implements the extensions. Can you show the API call that is crashing when you attempt to pass `GL_BGRA`?

Comment: I've added code in the original post. The actual crash happens when glDrawElements is called.

Comment: AH! I found the issue I think. I had a glEnableVertexAttribArray that wasn't pointing to anything. Commenting it out fixed the crash.

Comment: So it doesn't seem to do the trick, though at least the crash is gone. I'd like to make sure... 

According to DX9, the data is stored as 10,10,10,2. The one I am using though will be 2,10,10,10, with GL_BGRA just swapping the coord positions. The issue is still that the 2 bits are on the wrong side. While the wiki says this is how it's loaded, it doesn't seem to make sense. Would this actually work?

Comment: @Ioncannon: `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` by itself is effectively in `ABGR` order, the `GL_BGRA` option exists so that when you reverse that it works out to `ARGB` (a common component order used by D3D). Regarding the other part, D3D stores its data in little-endian byte order, so that packed 10_10_10_2 data type is a 32-bit word with the lowest byte being the most significant (which, in this case is the entire alpha channel plus part of another color). The bit order needs to be reversed for GL to read it correctly.

Comment: You can't get an OpenGL ES profile if your desktop environment doesn't support it. If you query a GL2ES2 profile, it can return a GL2 profile. You should look at the documentation: http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html